# Is there a real physical system which is modeled by DE which has non unique solution at its ICs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if there is a real physical system which could be represented and modeled using a differential equation, but the IVP DE has many solutions (not unique) at the initial point.